# Analytic functions in the extended complex plane with single pole

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Could any one please give me an idea to characterize the analytic functions on the extended complex plane with one single pole?

Comment: Can you characterise those whose only pole is $\infty$?

Comment: you mean the polynomials?

Comment: Yes. Well, the non-constant polynomials if we require an actual pole. Now, have you an idea what function you could compose a polynomial with to get a function having its only pole at $a$?